# How to figure out congruences involving large numbers?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

The one I'm stuck on now is:

$$3^{1996001} ≡ 2664001 \mod 3992003$$

Absolutely no idea how to get this! I could whittle it down if I knew the multiplicative order of $3$ modulo $3992003$, but I have no idea how to figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that 3992003=1997*1999?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to figure out? If the congruence is correct?

Comment: Define $a=3992003=2\cdot 1996001+1$. Then if $a$ were prime, the multiplicative group of integers  $\mod a$ would be cyclic of order $a-1$. The square roots of $1$ in this group would be $1$ and $a-1$ and would not include $2664001$. But this would contradict little Fermat applied to the square of the given congruence. Hence $a$ is not prime, and will have a prime factor less than $2000$.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm supposing you can find out that the prime factorization of $3992003$ is $1997*1999$.

First we solve $3^{1996001} (\text{mod } 1997)$. Since 1997 is prime we have

$$3^{1996}\equiv 1 (\text{mod }1997).$$

Now $1996001 = 1996 . 1000 + 1$, so

$$3^{1996001} \equiv 3^{1996*1000+1} \equiv (3^{1996})^{1000}.3 \equiv 1^{1000}.3 \equiv 3 \text{ (mod }1997).$$

Similarly, we have

$$ 3^{1998} \equiv 1 \text{ (mod }1999),$$

and $1996001=999*1998-1$, so

$$3^{1996001} \equiv 3^{999*1998-1} \equiv (3*1998)^{999}.3^{-1} \equiv 3^{-1}  \equiv -666  \text{ (mod }1999).$$

Now we want to solve the congruence problem:

$$\begin{align*}x &\equiv 3 &\text{ (mod 1997)}\\
 x &\equiv -666 &\text{ (mod 1999)}\end{align*}$$

We need integers $a$ and $b$ such that $1997a+1999b=1$. We have

$$1999 = 1.1997 +2$$
$$1997 = 2.998 + 1$$

So

$$ 1 = 1997 - 2.998 = 1997 - (1999 - 1997).998 = 1997.999 + 1999(-998).$$

Now if $\alpha=1997.999$, $\beta=1999(-998)$, we have

$$\alpha \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 1997)},\ \ \beta \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 1997)},$$
$$\alpha \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 1999)},\ \ \beta \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 1999)},$$

therefore $(-666)\alpha + 3\beta$ is a solution for $x$ in the above system, and

$$ (-666)\alpha + 3\beta= -666*1997*999 + 3*1999*(-998) = -1334657004 \equiv 2664001 \text{ (mod 3992003)}$$

Comment: How would you figure out that 3992003 = 1997*1999?

Comment: Knowing 3992003 is not prime (say, by Mark Bennet's comment), I may want to look for prime factors less than the square root of this number. Trying to take its square root I may realize that it's almost a square, in fact $3992004$ is $1998^2$, so $3992003 = 1998^2 - 1 = 1997 * 1999$. Or I could use Mathematica and then claim to have done it this way.

Comment: "Or I could use Mathematica and then claim to have done it this way." Such facts.